# "Business" email letter opening when their signed name is their language center?

Tags: business-japanese

How do I respond and open the letter when they're signing their emails with their language center name instead of their "person"-name?

They close with "「ｘ」センター"

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ご担当者様** is the equivalent of "to someone it may concern". You can use it like this:

```
Xセンター
ご担当者様

お世話になっております、……
```

From [a dictionary](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%94%E6%8B%85%E5%BD%93%E8%80%85%E3%81%95%E3%81%BE):

> 組織などに手紙や電子メールを送る際、対応する個人名が不明な場合に宛名として用いられる表現。「担当者さま」に丁寧の「ご」をつけた表現。