# How to address a company in an email?

Tags: politeness, greetings, email

When writing an email to a person I would add 様 or "sama" at the end of the name in the email opening. However if I'm writing to a company and don't know the recipient's name would I add "sama" as well at the end of the company name?

For example, if the company is called "Wasabi" would I open the email with "Wasabi様" ?

Comment: Also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32961/5010

Comment: @naruto so if I understand correctly, the answer is to add "御中" at the end of the company name which would translate to "Wasabi Staff" in the example above? And then below that write "ご担当者様" which is like "to whom it may concern" ?